# How to access external storage of devices according to API level in Android

Tags: android, android-studio

I am trying to create file directories to save log files. Since different API levels are supported to access external storage differently, I had to write my code to compatible with every API level. This is my code.

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
    // For Android 10 (API level 29) and above
    path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).toString();
} else {
    // For Android 9 (API level 28) and below
    path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
}
    File logsDir = new File(path + "/agent_logs");
    if (!logsDir.exists() && !logsDir.mkdirs()) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Unable to create directory");
    }
```

This code is perfectly worked for the devices under android level 10 and the devices above android level 10. It does not work for android level 10, API level 29. After adding this code, even the application is not opened in android 10 devices. What is the problem?

I have added these permissions to AndroidManifest.xml as well.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES"
        tools:ignore="QueryAllPackagesPermission" />

<application
        android:name=".MainApplication"
        android:allowBackup="false"
        android:fullBackupContent="false"
        android:fullBackupOnly="false"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
        tools:targetApi="31"
        android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
        >
```

Comment: `even the application is not opened in android 10 devices.` You app does not start? How can that be possible with those few lines of code that will not even be executed at startup.

Comment: @blackapps I have created a react-native package using Android to save log files. These code lines belong to that module. I call this package inside the MainActivity.java file. For other android levels this code is work perfectly. But it does not work only for android 10.  I have updated the question as well.

Comment: `even the application is not opened in android 10 devices.` Well you did not answer my remark. Please do.

Answer (score 0):

Add android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" to application tag in manifest file.

Comment: It is already added.

Comment: `have added these permissions to AndroidManifest.xml as well.` So you missed to tell that.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with Android 11 and above you need to change how you read/write data to external storage. Please refer to the [Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage) for more info. Please keep in mind the new permission `MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` and the `Storage Access Framework` found [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/document-provider)

```
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
    android:maxSdkVersion="32" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
    android:maxSdkVersion="32"/>
```

If its the case that you want to user to save the data themselves elsewhere then I recommend using an intent instead. Something along the lines of:

```
val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND)
intent.type = "application/pdf"
val uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(
    requireContext(),
    this.getString(R.string.fileprovider_authority),
    File(it)
)
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri)
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)

val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
    requireContext(),
    0,
    receiver,
    PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE
)
val chooser = Intent.createChooser(
    intent,
    getString("Chooser Title eg file name"),
    pendingIntent.intentSender
)

requireActivity().grantUriPermission(
    packageName,
    uri,
    Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION
)

this.startActivity(chooser)
```